# SharePoint Sandbox solution on subsite

Tags: event-receivers, sandbox-solution, sub-site

I try add sandbox solution to SharePoint 2013 on subsite with event reciver on list, and don't work ;(

On Root Web is O.K. event fired and do something what I wont, but when I activate feature on subsite then list was created but event don't working.

Does anyone know why? I don't have access to Farm server, so I can't doing something on web.config or Central Administration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try couple of steps to see event receiver is attached to a list

1. Check your scope.
2. Run powershell to see list of event receivers on SP List.

   ```
   $web=Get-SPWeb ">"
   $list = $web.Lists["list name"]
   $receivers=$list.EventReceivers
   ```

   you can refer link http://nikcharlebois.com/retrieving-a-list-of-event-receivers-using-powershell/
3. Or Use SPO browser tool to see event receivers from GUI
   you can download tool from here 
   https://spcb.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your feature has the correct scope **site** or **web**. This will determine when the EventReceiver fires.